# Launching program on computer without QT

Tags: c++, qt

I created my program and now trying to launch it on other computer.
I get following errors:

```
.../libQtGui.so.5: version 'Qt_5' not found
.../libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5' not found
.../libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.9' not found
.../libQt5Sql.so.5: version 'Qt_5' not found
.../libQt5Network.so.5: version 'Qt_5' not found
.../libQt5Widgets.so.5: version 'Qt_5' not found
```

I added script and this files to my application directory as it is decribed here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

But I still getting this errors. 
Does anyone knowes how in may be solved ?

Comment: are those libraries in the same directory as the application, or on the path?

Comment: @Neil at the same directory as the application

Comment: Are you sure about those paths?  ``.../`` sounds suspicious.  Either way, those libraries aren't in the correct directory, The app expects them to be in ``...``, not ``.``.

Comment: @Neil the whole error code looks like .../MyAppDirectory/ ./MyAppScript: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version 'Qt_5' not found

Comment: Please read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html